# i have a 1980's teamade, something is all over the bottom, i can't get it off/out, would you consider this safe to drink from? what is it? fixable?

Tags: food-safety, tea, kettle

as you can see, something is all over the place in the bottom of the kettle around the edges?  can i remove them, can this be fixed?  its great and i have been drinking from it every morning but i worry, obviously!

[image]

Comment: the photo didn't load
https://files.catbox.moe/vd76fx.jpg
https://files.catbox. moe/vd76fx.jpg remove space thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to use a tea kettle with black dots on the bottom?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43561/is-it-safe-to-use-a-tea-kettle-with-black-dots-on-the-bottom)

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm voting to close this as it's a duplicate of another question, although you have white dots it's the same answer - mineral deposits which don't impact safety in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

This is aluminum oxidation and it's there because the previous user left it over to dry by itself. I have some aluminum mokas and managed to get this earlier. This level of aluminum is safe to ingest and otherwise it's the same thing GdD said to you in a comment

Comment: i didn't see a comment other than yours, is there anything you suggest i do Damian?  vinegar, baking soda, etc, etc, is there anything i can do, and you would feel safe drinking out of it daily?  thanks in advance, and thank you for your answer.

Comment: The suggestion is to ignore it.  It's just cosmetic.